# How to get the bounds of an attachment bodypart of a mime?

Tags: c#, mimekit

I am trying to segment the mime, extracting the attachments from the raw mime, but when I get the content the stream doesn't always supply the starting bound of the mime, is there a way I can get it using Mimekit?

Comment: A mime attachment start with two returns and then two dashes.

Comment: @jdweng, I am trying to do so by using mimekit, since I still need need to parse it to get some more information. So I was trying to find a way to do so without traversing the mime again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to use the MimeParser directly (instead of MimeMessage.Load if that's what you are using now) and attach to the [MimeEntityBegin](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/E_MimeKit_MimeParser_MimeEntityBegin.htm) event which will provide you with the byte offsets of each MIME entity within the message as it is parsed.

in other words, you could do something like this:

```
var beginOffsets = new Dictionary<MimeEntity, long> ();
parser.MimeEntityBegin += (s, e) => {
    beginOffsets.Add (e.Entity, e.BeginOffset);
};
var message = parser.ParseMessage ();

foreach (var bodyPart in message.BodyParts) {
    var beginOffset = beginOffsets[bodyPart];
}
```